# polymer - page content isnt rendered

Tags: polymer-1.0

Can anyone help me here? im (totally) new at polymer. And im having trouble with rendering the content.

One page named "o-primeiro-demo.html" isnt rendering. I can only get the content present in the index.html file when i get it either through  localhost:8080 or localhost/php.

This is the code:

index.html(what i added. the rest is the inicial settings)

```
<link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="o-primeiro-demo.html">
<body>where is "o-primeiro-demo.html" data?</body>
```

o-primeiro-demo.html

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<dom-module id="o-primeiro-demo">
     <template>This is the first test</template>
     <script>Polymer ({ is : "o-primeiro-demo" }); </script>
</dom-module>
```

bower.json

```
"name": "o-primeiro-demo",
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to show o-primeiro-demo in your page.

For Polymer, to show a page you have to stamp it out onto the page with a tag.

If you want that to show up you need to write:

`<body> 
    <o-premeiro-demo></o-premeiro-demo> 
  </body>`

Until you do this, all content is inert. It doesn't exist and nothing knows about it.

Comment: No, that doesnt work. It continues to only show the content present in index.html.

Comment: If you haven't already, try running ` polymer init starter-kit `. I have a feeling the issue is somewhere in the dependencies. Looking at that may help since I can't see your file structure

Comment: dependencies:"app-layout": "PolymerElements/app-layout#^0.10.0"

Comment: dependencies: "app-layout": "PolymerElements/app-layout#^0.10.0"----"app-route": "PolymerElements/app-route#^0.9.0"----"iron-flex-layout": "PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout#^1.0.0"----"iron-icon": "PolymerElements/iron-icon#^1.0.0"----"iron-iconset-svg": "PolymerElements/iron-iconset-svg#^1.0.0"----"iron-localstorage": "PolymerElements/iron-localstorage#^1.0.0"----"iron-media-query": "PolymerElements/iron-media-query#^1.0.0"----"iron-pages": "PolymerElements/iron-pages#^1.0.0"----"iron-selector": "PolymerElements/iron-selector#^1.0.0" ----(continues)

Comment: (continuation)----"polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.6.0"----thats it, i havent added any dependency to the bower.json file.